# MomentJS issue handling Feb 29th when not a Leap year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am validating against invalid dates like 36/12/2013 (DD/MM/YYYY), 2/15/2013 (DD/MM/YYYY) or the following specific case:

**29/02/2009** (DD/MM/YYYY) which is invalid as 2009 is **not** a Leap year

The code is:

```
var momentAcceptedDateInputs = ['D/M/YY', 'DD/M/YY','D/MM/YY','DD/MM/YY'
, 'D/M/YYYY', 'DD/M/YYYY', 'D/MM/YYYY', 'DD/MM/YYYY',
'D MMM YY', 'DD MMM YY', 'D MMM YYYY', 'DD MMM YYYY'];

var parsedDate = moment(val, momentAcceptedDateInputs);
return parsedDate.isValid();
```

**Entered Value:**

29/02/2009

**Expected** Returned Values for objects:

1. parsedDate.isValid(): **false**
2. parsedDate: Moment

   - _a: Array[7]
   - _d: **Sun Feb 29 2009 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)**
   - _f: "D/M/YYYY"
   - _i: "29/02/2009"
   - _isUTC: false
   - _isValid: **false**

**Actual** Returned Values for objects:

1. parsedDate.isValid(): **true**
2. parsedDate: Moment

   - _a: Array[7]
   - _d: **Sun Feb 29 1920 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)**
   - _f: "D/M/YY"
   - _i: "29/02/2009"
   - _isUTC: false
   - _isValid: **true**

Any idea how to fix this??

I am using a customised version of moment.js version : 2.4.0

The only rule I have customised is this so I doubt it will cause the bug reported above:

```
datePartArray[YEAR] = toInt(input) + 
(toInt(input) > (moment(moment()).format("YY")) ? 1900 : 2000);
```

Comment: So you've customized 3rd party library? That's not very maintainable. What if this *is* a bug and it will be fixed in a future version; how do you plan to update then?

Comment: Have you tried your code with the unmodified version of moment.js just to eliminate the possibility that your customization may be responsible?

Comment: I update the library and then replace the default rules with my customised rules.
What other options do I have since this value (68) is hardcoded into the library
datePartArray[YEAR] = toInt(input) + (toInt(input) > 68 ? 1900 : 2000);

Comment: I believe this code is making a full year based on the last two digits. I see two options: a) always use for digits for year; b) write a function helper that will convert two-digit to for-digit notation before passing to Moment. Also you could try to open an issue in their bugtracker. Modifying 3rd-library source code is the last thing you should be doing.

Comment: Pavlo, I agree, and I have this as a to do task. The requirements specify 2 and 4 digits years so the first option is out of the question. The helper function will include a lot of the parsing rules and methods from the moment library. I will have to do it eventually if they don't resolve it after putting this on their bug-tracker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moment's parser is very forgiving by default.

For example:

```
moment("29/02/2009",'D/M/YY').isValid()  // true, because it uses year "20"
```

You can change this by passing a boolean true

```
moment("29/02/2009",'D/M/YY', true).isValid() // false, due to the year digits
```

[This is in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: The problem is not with the .isValid() method. 
The problem is that the parser parses this incorrectly in the first place. Look at the returned moment object:
var parsedDate = moment(val, momentAcceptedDateInputs);

Comment: I was just using `isValid` as an example.  The boolean is passed as an argument when parsing using the `moment()` function.

Comment: So you would use `var parsedDate = moment(val, momentAcceptedDateInputs, true);`

Comment: This seems to return the correct moment object and year. Thanks again Matt.

Answer (score 1):

As for moment-2.10.6,

```
 moment("29/02/2009", "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid();
```

now returns **false** even without the strict parsing flag.

Moreover, the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) says that customizing the parsing of two-digit years can be done by "replacing the moment.parseTwoDigitYear method".

Something like:

```
var moment = require("moment");

var myMoment = module.exports = moment;

moment.parseTwoDigitYear = function(year) {
    return ((year > 20)? 1000:2000) + parseInt(year);
}
```

and then

```
myMoment = require('./myMoment');

date = myMoment("28/02/67", "DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log(date.year());
```

returns **1067** (not **2067**).

Answer (score 0):

More so posting my own sanity when I run to this years later.

```js
moment(input, ['MM/DD/yy', 'MM/DD/YYYY'], true).isValid()
```

For some weird reason, I have to lowercase `yy` for years with 2 digits, and `YYYY` for full years.

Accidently figured this out with this jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lgdmeuk0/

My mind cannot process why this works. But it does. Nani!